# Why does System.Timers.Timer create multiple threads when it fires the Elapsed events?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, system.timers.timer

When I create a `System.Timers.Timer` such as...

```
private System.Timers.Timer m_checker = new System.Timers.Timer();
public MyClass()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("[threadid:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "] Main Thread");
    m_checker.Elapsed += m_checker_Elapsed;
    m_checker.Interval = 1000;
    m_checker.Start();
}

private void m_checker_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("[threadid:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "]");
}
```

### Results with interval set to 1000:

```
/*
[threadid:10] Main Thread
[threadid:7]
[threadid:7]
[threadid:7]
[threadid:12]
[threadid:7]
[threadid:12]
etc...
*/
```

### Results with interval set to 2000:

```
/*
[threadid:10] Main Thread
[threadid:7]
[threadid:7]
[threadid:7]
[threadid:7]
etc...
*/
```

I see that the `Elapsed` event is showing different threads when it is firing.  Although when I change the `Interval` value to something higher such as 2000 (instead of the 1000) it seems to stay on the same thread.

Why is that?

I'm wanting a timer that fires on it's own thread but just fires on the one thread and not multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does it because that's the way it was written.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

> The server-based System.Timers.Timer class is designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment. Server timers can move among threads to handle the raised Elapsed event . . .

FWIW, Microsoft recommends that you not use it:

> The Timer class is available in the .NET Framework only. It is not included in the .NET Standard Library and is not available on other platforms, such as .NET Core or the Universal Windows Platform. On these platforms, as well as for portability across all .NET platforms, you should use the System.Threading.Timer class instead.

The Timer class is now available in the .NET Standard Library as of .NET Standard 2.0. Obviously, the comment above was correct when it was written...3+ years ago. If you need to go back to .Net Standard Version 1.6 or sooner, then YES, the above comment is accurate.

Comment: Roger that.  So will the System.Threading.Timer class handle it differently or the same?

Comment: That's multithreaded also. Is it a problem somehow? If you can use it, System.Windows.Forms.Timer is single threaded.

Comment: Yea it's a problem for me.  In my situation the timer is checking and editing a shared memory space.  When the timer on thread1 reads the memory and starts to work, the timer on thread2 fires up and reads before thread1 completes.  So they read the same variable value.  It's kinda crazy if the timing is just right it's almost like the second thread counter acts the first thread...  :)  I just thought I was doing something wrong.  Now that I know what is happening I can make changes to the code to account for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It uses the thread pool to execute the handlers.  Depending on what your program is doing, your thread pool might have one thread in it, or many, and you may or may not have different threads handling any given request.

Comment: Thanks for your insight as well Servy! +1